# share a constant variable between rails model and angularjs controllers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm looking for a cool idea how to share a constant value between a model (of ruby on rails) and a controller (of angularjs).
Before started using angular I used to hold some values in a constant variable of my models, eg:

```
class MyModel << ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :sample1
  OPTIONAL_VALUES = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5']
end
```

This way I could use the `OPTIONAL_VALUES` in both my views (in order to populate a select tag for example) and my model validations (in order to validate that sample1 won't get any value which is not in the list).

But now, my client side and my views are separate from the "rails side" and managed my AngularJS, and I still need to use the same `OPTIONAL_VALUES` array. I don't want to repeat the code, do you have any idea how I can achieve it?

Comment: First thing that springs to mind, a cookie?

Comment: you should create a service bearing this kind of "constants"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ng-init to pass them like:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="inti('<%= stringify MyModel.OPTIONAL_VALUES with rails here %>')"/>
```

And in your controller you create a method init like:

```
function init(ov) {
     this.optionalValues = JSON.parse(ov);
}
```